# prove the existance of $U$ and $V$ Neighbourhoods of $X_0$ and $F(X_0)$ so that $F_{|U}$ is a diffeomorphism in $V$

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, matrix-equations

> we have $E = M_n(R)$ and :
>
> $$F : E \to E ,  F(X) = X^2 + X - I$$
>
> we need to prove the existance of $U\in \mathscr V(X_0)$ and $V\in
> > \mathscr V(0_E)$ so that  $F_{|U}$ (restriction function) is a
>   diffeomorphism from $U$ to $V$ .
>
> with $X_0 = \alpha I / \alpha = \frac{( \sqrt5 - 1 )}{2} $ so we have
>   $F(X_0)=0_E$

i also proved in another question that $F\in C^1$ in $E$ but i dont know how to start anything here !

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to apply the local inversion theorem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @DennisGulko: Well, it actually partially answers the question. But I agree Saïd should add some details (checking we indeed have the required conditions to apply it).